# Change "To:" field when auto-forwarding email in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I am trying to use a Gmail address (`my.printer@gmail.com`) automatically to forward email to my printer (`djfhsjshkjghsfkjfhlgfhd@hpeprint.com`) because the printer's address is extremely unmemorable.

The problem I'm having is that when Gmail forwards the email, it doesn't replace the "TO" field, so emails arrive at the `hpeprint.com` address with a `gmail.com` address in the "TO" field, and then the hpeprint server rejects them.

> ePrint Error: The ‘TO’ or ‘CC’ field of the email you sent did not include a printer email address.

Does anyone know if there's a way to create a rule that adds the forwarding address into the TO or CC field?

Comment: From my point of view, the easiest solution is to add a contact with a name easy to recall and include the printer email as its email.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this? I am trying to do the same thing. I have an idea of how to fix it with a custom php programming script but trying to find a simple solution. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a different email address you can create a contact for this monstrosity

> 'djfhsjshkjghsfkjfhlgfhd@hpeprint.com'

This way you can just type in the contact info and it should work.

In order to accomplish this use these steps taken from [this](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/save-email-addresses-gmail-42846.html) website:

> 1. Log in to your Gmail account. Enter your login name and password. Click the "Sign in" button. You are directed to your Gmail Inbox.
> 2. Click the "Gmail" link near the top-left of the page, below the "Google" logo and above the "Compose" button. A drop-down menu
>      appears.
> 3. Click the "Contacts" link in the drop-down menu.
> 4. Click the Add to "My Contacts" button near the top of the Contacts window. This button has an icon of a head-and-shoulders silhouette of
>      a person on it and a "+" sign.
> 5. Enter the email address for the person you wish to add to your contacts. Click the "add" link. The email address is saved to your
>      contacts list.

Let me know if you have any further issues.